# CSS - input:invalid not

Tags: css, validation, input

I'm having a validation problem ...
If I put select field like this:
It already appears invalid, even without

```
<option value=''></option>
```

If I put the select field like this:

It stays right without even touching

```
    <option value=' '></option>
```

I want it to only begin to validate after selecting

Follows his CSS

```css
.form-validate input:invalid, textarea:invalid, select:invalid {
  background: url(../img/error.png) no-repeat 98% center;
  border: 1px solid #ebccd1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #d45252;
  color: #a94442;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwDT6.png)

How can I leave to just check if it invalid when submitting the Submit, because when I select 'select' (this is already working) ...

I thought about using the:

```
input :not (:empty)
```

because I understand that this would identify if when the value is not 'empty', it does nothing ... but it did not work

Comment: Welceom to SO. Please improve your formatting by restructuring some wording. The "enter image description" shoud state ... something that makes sense.

Comment: Please could you create a [MCVE] in your code snippet.  It will be easier for us to see what your problem is

Comment: Can you begin by clarifying if your question is about `input` or `option`?

Comment: Sorry, I will reformulate